# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver

Tags: java, apache, jdbc

I'm new to this site.

I've been having trouble connecting to my Java DB I have created. I've used the following code but given

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver

as an error.

```
String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/db;create=true;user=Administrator";

String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";

// login and connection details above
try {
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    Statement s = conn.createStatement();

    System.out.println("connected!");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error in dbConnection " + e);
    System.out.println(e.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in DBconnection , consult developers!");
}
```

I've tried going through many forums and feeds and none of the advice given seems to work.

Comment: You miss the jar which contains the class as a dependency

Comment: At minimum show us how you run your application and how your class path is configured. You need to make sure the driver is on the class path used by your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `JAR` which contains the class `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver` which is `derbyclient.jar`

You can download and add this jar to the classpath from [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/derby/derbyclient/10.14.1.0/derbyclient-10.14.1.0.jar)

Or, If you're using maven for building, you can add the following to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
    <version>10.14.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```